# Connect two random users from Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m trying to create an app where I need to match two random users from my Firebase Database. The problem I have is that I‘m not sure how to connect every user of the database to random pairs: 
As far as I thought the user might press a button to signal that he‘s ready, so a child of his UID like 'searching' turns from false to true. By receiving a DataSnapshot the user can see if another user is searching too. Then I thought of turning the 'searching' state to false for both users and create a new UniqueID to connect them.

But like that it‘s thought pretty short, I think and would cause some problems. Can anyone give me a hint on how to organize that searching process?

Comment: Hey @user9582784 if my answer helped you solve your problem, then do mark it as correct by clicking on tick mark V type button next to to it, and upvote it. This helps future readers of this question and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Comment: Yeah, I won‘t forget it, I didn‘t have enough time to spend it on that, so I‘m still checking if everything works for me, then I‘ll immediately mark it as correct! :)

Comment: Isn‘t it possible that two user get a snapshot at the same time and may randomly choose the same other user? I guess it‘s a quite low danger, but is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: In the algorithm I have told you in the answer, we follow just one thing, we find people who are searching and then just randomly get a number, from the number of `id's` we have. In random numbers, there's a possibility that two people may choose one another, but that's what it is, and nothing I think, can be done about it, also random should mean, not in our hands to control and it is that.

Comment: Okay, that sounds right. So do you think that case would be negligible?

Comment: Yes, if we are taking about Random, then it should be, but possibilities are there, but that is what it is, I guess.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually using a special node like `searching` and setting it to `true` and `false` will be a good idea.

You can use `orderByChild()` to order all the users with `searching` node set to `true` and get the uid of any of those users.

To make the process random you could make a call to users, take the ids given back to you, and pick one at random with a basic random number.

If after making a call to users you have 10 user ids in an array you would want to get a random number between 0-9 and then make a call to firebase with the userId.

I don't believe Firebase has any built in code for this. So this would be the best thing you can do to achieve this feature in your app.

To give a basic idea, your database structure should look something like this:

```json
--rootNode
|
|
  -- uid1
| |
|  - searching
|  - other Fields
|
  -- uid2

  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much so far! I‘m gonna try it like this and let you know if it worked for me :)