# Connect random users in Google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have a set of users which mark their status as online. I want to connect two random users in Firebase and my database is a Firestore Database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Please post the code which you have already tried and point out specific problems which we can help you with

Comment: I haven't tried any code yet. I have completed only user authentication using firebase authentication.I have list of users in user collection.I am using android as client side.I want know logic how it work

Comment: @Akashkv do mark the answer as correct, if it helped you start working on this, I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Comment: thank you all for the downvoting.It helped me to learn how StackOverflow works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not posted any code or idea of your own, hence I can't comment or tell you very specific things to your idea/code. But I'd try to be broad enough for this.

Using a special node like `status` and setting it to `online` and `offline` will be a good idea.

You can use `orderByChild()` to order all the users with `status` node set to `online` and get the `uid` of any of those users.

To make the process random you could make a call to `users`, take the ids given back to you, and pick one at random with a basic random number.

If after making a call to users you have 10 user ids in an array you would want to get a random number between 0-9 and then make a call to firebase with the userId.

I don't believe Firebase has any built in code for this. So this would be the best thing you can do to achieve this feature in your app.

[You may also refer this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467067/connect-two-random-users-from-database/53467120#53467120)